# Regression turns out unknown intercepts

Tags: r

I have an issue with R, I tried to run the regression and it turns out to be something I did not except and understand.

Can you help?

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the intercepts should be X1, X2 etc....

Comment: Are you sure the X's are of type numeric?